# Error when trying to print a procedure Scheme

Tags: function, printing, scheme, procedure

My objective is to make a procedure which subtracts one TriVol from another but unfortunately I keep getting this error:

> contract violation
>     expected: number?
>     given: #
>     argument position: 1st
>     other arguments.

(The error occurs on the DiffVol procedure)
What is the meaning of the error and why is it happening and how do I fix it? Thank you!

```
(define (TriArea base height) (* height (/ base 2)))



(define (TriVol)
  (define base (read))
  (define height (read))
  (define depth (read))
  (* depth (TriArea base height))
  (display (* depth (TriArea base height))))


(define (DiffVol)
  (display(- (Trivol) (TriVol))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that each function returns the value of its last form. So, the reason for the error is that the function `TriVol` does not return an integer, but a void value, since its last form is `display`.

So, in function `DiffVol`, the form `(- (TriVol) (TriVol))`, that should do the difference between two integers, finds two void values and gives the error.

To correct the error, simply change the code of `TriVol` to return the right value.